# Using different ormconfig.json files depending on env

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

My ormconfig.json is static of course, it looks like:

```
{
   "type": "mariadb",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 3306,
   "username": "root",
   "password": "moove",
   "database": "moove_db",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": false,
   "entities": [
      "dist/entity/**/*.js"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "dist/migration/**/*.js"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "dist/subscriber/**/*.js"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "dist/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "dist/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "dist/subscriber"
   }
}
```

but what if I want to create another config for our production server?
Do I create another config file? How do I point typeorm to the other config file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the moment, I was able to just change `ormconfig.json`, to `ormconfig.js`, and then use env variables, like this:

```
module.exports = {
   "port": process.env.port,
   "entities": [
      // ...
   ],
   "migrations": [
      // ...
   ],
   "subscribers": [
     // ...
   ],
   "cli": {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the ormconfig.json. You can pass a config object directly to createConnection() like

```
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";

const config:any = {
       "port": process.env.port || "28017",
       "entities": [
          // ...
       ],
       "migrations": [
          // ...
       ],
       "subscribers": [
         // ...
       ],
       "cli": {
          // ...
       }
    }
    createConnection(config).then(async connection => {
        await loadPosts(connection);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: you can also type it as `const config: ConnectionOptions` (imported from `typeorm`)

Comment: TypeORM CLI cannot be used with this approach.